# Windows Mobile Pocket PC 2003 application "remote name cannot be resolved" exception when apppemt to connect web service

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application (on visual strudio 2005 sp1) and I get this exception when I try to reach the web service(written on sap). But this is not all.

When I run the app on emulator on computer(connecting internet with cable) it works fine. Also I installed the app to mobile device and no problem BUT only with cradle, I mean only works when it connected to computer with cable of cradle.

Problem starts if the app try to connect web service via wireless connection of our customer's internet.(unplugging from cradle).

I figured out that if I write the WSDL link in IP form, device connects to web service(on wireless)(but not via code, by copying link to text file and clicking to it) but on other form device can't find web service's page. I added the IP of web service to hosts file but problem still exists.

Comment: Maybe your device does not have the wireless radio turned on. Can you get to someplace on your network when it is not cradled?

Comment: Actually device connects to web service link(IP formed) by entering manually on browser(on wireless) but not by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by taking web service address from sap transaction sicf.